# gulp - passing args to tasks called in the runSequence

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I have a gulp task configured like so:

```
gulp.task('concatenate_client_js', function(){
  return merge2(
      gulp.src('./gulp/buildConfig.json')
        .pipe(plugins.ngConfig('app.envConfig', {
          environment: 'development'
        })
      ),
      gulp.src(paths.clientJS)
    )
    .pipe(plugins.concat('angular_app.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.distScripts));
});
```

This task is then called in the runSequence of other tasks (split across different gulp files) I have like so:

```
gulp.task('prepare-dev-files', function(callback){
  runSequence('clean_dist_dir', 'copy_assets', 'copy_serverFiles', 'copy_bower_css',
  ['compile_bower_sass', 'concatonate_bower_js'],
  'compile_sass', 'concatenate_client_js', 'compile_main_js', callback);
});

gulp.task('prepare-staging-files',  ['prepare-dev-files'], function(callback) {
  runSequence('clean_test_src', 'copy_unitTestFiles', 'copy_files_for_coverage_report', 'karma_tests_ci', callback)
});
```

What I would like to be able to do is to set the `environment`config option to the `ngConfig` plugin in the `concatenate_client_js` task based on args or params supplied to the task.

I have seen tools like yargs but am unsure how to use in my case. I would like to be able to supply an arg e.g `--mode development` to the call to my task in the runSequence's, e.g.

```
gulp.task('prepare-staging-files',  ['prepare-dev-files --mode staging'], function(callback) {
      runSequence('clean_test_src', 'copy_unitTestFiles', 'copy_files_for_coverage_report', 'karma_tests_ci', callback)
    });
```

And then add some switch code based on the mode argument passed to the task.

Is this achievable?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is achievable. You can utilize the [yargs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs) module to do this. The `argv` property of the `yargs` module is available for all the gulp tasks defined in the `gulpfile.js`. Here is an example:

```
var gulp   = require('gulp');

var args   = require('yargs').argv;

gulp.task('a', function() {
  console.log('Arguments for A: ', args.env);
});

gulp.task('b', function() {
  console.log('Arguments for B: ', args.env);
});

gulp.task('c', ['a', 'b'], function() {
  console.log('Arguments for C: ', args.env);
});
```

The command `$ gulp c --env development` gives the following output:

> 14:42:01] Starting 'a'...
>
> Arguments for A:  development
>
> [14:42:01] Finished 'a' after 175 μs
>
> [14:42:01] Starting 'b'...
>
> Arguments for B:  development
>
> [14:42:01] Finished 'b' after 67 μs
>
> [14:42:01] Starting 'c'...
>
> Arguments for C:  development
>
> [14:42:01] Finished 'c' after 51 μs